# How can I unit-test weakly named COM visible classes

Tags: c#, unit-testing, com

I have a **COM visible** class (marked with `[ComVisible(true)]` and registered with RegAsm) in C# that I want to unit-test.
My assembly is an unsigned/weakly named dll (and it has to remain this). The class that I want to test has a **private member** that is not COM visible.
My problem is when I want to instantiate this class in a test it fails with this message:

> Test method %MyTestMethod% threw exception
>   System.EnterpriesServices.RegistreationException: The assembly
>   %MyAssembly% does not have a strong name.

So how can I use the unit-test framework on an unsigned/weakly named dll?

```
using System.EnterpriseServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[ComVisible( true )]
public class MyComClass: ServicedComponent, IMyClass
{
    //SomeAttribute

    private MyNonComClass nonCom;

    public MyComClass( MyNonComClass _nonCom )
    {
        this.nonCom = _nonCom;
    }
}
```

Comment: A unit test should never try to register a [ComVisible] assembly, you left no breadcrumb to explained how that happened.  Consider Project > Properties > Build tab, "Register for COM interop" checkbox.  It will not object against an unsigned assembly.  But beware that VS must run elevated.  Not deploying the assembly into the GAC on the user's machine (requires a strong name) is a pretty bad idea.  COM has very strong DLL Hell problems since registration is machine-wide.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I modified my original description in hope it has some hints.

Comment: The MSDN docs for ServicedComponent is quite explicit: "To deploy this class as a configured COM component, you must generate a strong key"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Hans Passant suggested when I removed the ServicedComponent class from inheritance, the unit-tests are running as supposed.

Comment: It is *not* arbitrary.  The difference between an in-process COM server and an out-of-process server is a huge one.  If you meant to have it run out-of-process by design then you didn't actually test it the way it is going to be used.  Always favor in-process by design.